# Eloquent hasMany Not Returning Any Results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a noob question about how Eloquent generates SQL for the following.

DB:

- **Customer Table**:

  - ID (Public Key)
  - ... (Some general columns)
- **Group Table**:

  - ID (Public Key)
  - FK_CUSTOMER_ID (Foreign Key)
  - ... (Some general columns)

I have the following code in Customer Model:

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Group::class, 'fk_customer_id');
}
```

I am trying to get all groups (in the groups function above), that I can narrow down the groups later, to a particular customer.

The above code generates the following SQL (which results an empty result set, which is understandable by looking at the SQL). I have no idea, why the where clause (see the SQL below) gets generated, does not makes much sense.

```
select * from `group` where `group`.`fk_customer_id` is null and `group`.`fk_customer_id` is not null limit 1
```

I would like the following SQL to be generated :

```
select * from `group`
```

also, how to get the following SQL generated (If I need to select groups based on customer_id, I believe I'll need to add some where clause somehow)

```
select * from `group` where `group`.`fk_customer_id`= SOME_VALUE
```

Thanks!

--- Customer Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get ALL groups for the customer.
     */
    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Group::class, 'fk_customer_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get ONE group for the customer.
     */
    public function group($groupId)
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Group::class, 'fk_customer_id')->where('id', $groupId);
    }

     /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'customer';
}
```

Group Model

---

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Group;
use App\Customer;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get ONE customer for the group.
     */
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'fk_customer_id');
    }


    /**
     * Get ONE directory configuration for the group.
     */
    public function directoryConfiguration()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DirectoryConfiguration::class, 'fk_directory_configuration_id');
    }


    /**
     * Get ONE user for the group.
     */
    public function user($userId)
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'fk_role_id')->where('user_id', $userId);
    }

    /**
     * Get ALL user for the group.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'fk_role_id');
    }

     /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'group';
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `Customer` model class code? And also, how are you invoking the `groups` function to generate that query?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the model class for the both Customer and Group.

Comment: I am invoking groups function in the Customer model to get ALL the groups. So bascially, I am looking for following SQL to be generated: "select * from groups"

Comment: is the relation supposed to be many-to-many? if yes change both to BelongsToMany

Comment: The Customer table does not link (not FK) to Group Table. The Group is linked to Customer table (FK in Group table, points to Customer Table). Its not many to many relationship.

Comment: When defining the second argument to hasMany or belongsTo etc, it is the name of the column in the db not the actual name of the foreign key. So maybe it should be instead `$this->hasMany(Group::class, 'customer_id')` which would mean that the Customer would have many groups (Where group.customer_id matches). If you would like to receive all the groups of a customer you need to find the customer and then retrieve all the groups something like this> `Customer::find(1)->groups()->get()`. Additionally this doesn't make much sense `Get ONE group for the customer`... Simply use Group::find($id).

Comment: Thanks Artur. The problem with this approach  Customer::find(1)->groups()->get() is, that I dont have the id, I have the userId, from there I need to find the group (there can be only one group) and then from the group, I need to find the customer. But anyways, I am not sure what changes, but I can get the customer fine now. May be there was some php classes that were cached, and I had to restart the PC, that might have cleared the cache and regenerated them again. Thanks all for your time!

Comment: Show me how you use the relation? `groups` in `Customer` class is an `attribute`, it's not function. You declare wrong relation and a I think you also don't know how to use it.